# Input array size error for a quadraple integration using nested integral2

Tags: matlab

I need to perform a quadruple integration using `integral2` function in matlab. The code is below:

```
Rb = @(rho_1,phi_1) rho_1.*cos(phi_1);
Sb = @(rho_2,phi_2) rho_2.*cos(phi_2);
Tb = @(rho_1,phi_1,rho_2,phi_2) rho_1.*cos(phi_1)-rho_2.*cos(phi_2);
InnerIntegrand = @(rho_1,phi_1,rho_2,phi_2) Rb(rho_1,phi_1).*Sb(rho_2,phi_2).*Tb(rho_1,phi_1,rho_2,phi_2);
InnerIntegral = @(rho_1,phi_1) integral2(@(rho_2,phi_2) InnerIntegrand(rho_1,phi_1,rho_2,phi_2),0,3,0,2*pi);
II = integral2(InnerIntegral,0,3,0,2*pi);
```

Where `InnerIntegrand (rho_1,phi_1,rho_2,phi_2)` is the integrand. The `InnerIntegral` evaluates over `rho_2` and `phi_2`, which is being called from an outer `integral2` (integration over `rho_1` and `phi_1`).

I get an error:

> ```
> Error using  .* 
> Matrix dimensions must agree.
>
> Error in @(rho_1,phi_1,rho_2,phi_2)Rb(rho_1,phi_1).*Sb(rho_2,phi_2).*Tb(rho_1,phi_1,rho_2,phi_2)
>
>
> Error in @(rho_2,phi_2)InnerIntegrand(rho_1,phi_1,rho_2,phi_2)
>
>
> Error in integral2Calc>integral2t/tensor (line 238)
>         Z1 = FUN(X(VTSTIDX),Y(VTSTIDX)); NFE = NFE + 1;
> ```

Is the error coming due to different array sizes of two `integral2` calls? What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141102/quadruple-integral-using-nested-integral2-in-matlab/25143106#25143106). 
In your case, you can use

```
integral2(@(rho_1,phi_1)arrayfun(InnerIntegral,rho_1,phi_1),0,3,0,2*pi)
```