# definite 4D integration in octave, with functions as limits

Tags: matlab, octave, integral, calculus

I need to do 4D integration in octave.
My function is `f(x,y,phi,theta)` and some of the integration limits are function of the outer limits.

```
0 < theta < pi
t1(x,y) < phi < t2(x,y)
h1 < y < h2
w1 < x < w2
```

I wrote in octave like this (generalization):

```
[q1(i)] = integral( @(x) (integral3( @(y, phi, theta) f3(x, y, phi, theta), h1 , h2 , @(x,y) t1(x,y), @(x,y) t2(x,y), 0, pi)), w1, w2, 'ArrayValued',true);
```

my actual code:

```
clear all;
clc;
rho_bulk = 2.44; # rho_bulk = 2.44 uOhm.cm
h = 20e-9;
p = 0.5;
lambda = 40e-9;
n = 10;
w = linspace(20e-9,80e-9,n);

  for i = 1:n
  # limit for theta
  p2    = pi;
  p1    = 0;

  # limit for phi
  p4    = @(x,y) atan(x/(h-y)) + (pi/2);
  p3    = @(x,y) -atan((h-y)/(w(i)-x));

  # limit for y
  p6    = h;
  p5    = 0;

  # limit for x
  p8(i) = w(i);
  p7    = 0;

  #   f(x, y, phi, theta); outer --> inner
  #   limits;              inner --> outer

  f1 = @(x, y, phi, theta) exp(-(h-y)/(lambda *sin(theta) *sin(phi)));  
  f3 = @(x, y, phi, theta) sin(theta).*cos(theta).^2 .* f1(x, y, phi, theta);

  [q1(i)] = integral( @(x) (integral3( @(y, phi, theta) f3(x, y, phi, theta), p5, p6, @(x,y) p3(x,y), @(x,y) p4(x,y), p1, p2)), p7, p8(i), 'ArrayValued',true);
```

I have error from the integration line

```
error: 'y' undefined near line 51 column 98
```

I learned about the integration by following these:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/77571-how-to-perform-4d-integral-in-matlab

[Quadruple Integral Using Nested Integral2 in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141102/quadruple-integral-using-nested-integral2-in-matlab)

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: The  4D integration line.

```
[q1(i)] = integral( @(x) (integral3( @(y, phi, theta) f3(x, y, phi, theta), p5, p6, @(x,y) p3(x,y), @(x,y) p4(x,y), p1, p2)), p7, p8(i), 'ArrayValued',true);
```

Comment: You are missing some function (`p3`, `p4`, `p8` for instance) and parameter (`p5`, `p6`, etc.) definitions. Please [edit] your question and show a [mcve]. We can't debug code we can neither fully see nor can run.

Comment: I edit my post above.
if this help narrowing down the problem, I have doubt about the 4d integration line and its limits.

Comment: My octave 4.0.3 doesn't have functions named `integral` or `integral2`.

Comment: I use Octave 4.4.1

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry, I didn't notice that function [on the docs page](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Functions-of-One-Variable.html#Functions-of-One-Variable). Unfortunately that version of octave is incompatible with my system so I probably won't be able to help. For what it's worth I don't see where that error may be coming from. Perhaps the parser misunderstands what belongs to which anonymous function (what additional parentheses could fix), but I'm only guessing here.

Comment: do you think it is ok to write this
`f1 = @(x, y, phi, theta) exp(-(h-y)/(lambda *sin(theta) *sin(phi))); `?
f1 is not a function of x, y at the moment, but after the integration, it will.

deleting x,y in that functin definition gives the same error.

Comment: `p3(x,y), p4(x,y) instead of @(x,y) p3(x,y)` tried this as well. same error.

see here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/77571-how-to-perform-4d-integral-in-matlab

I still dont understand it though.

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood what you were trying to do which I realized after reading the docs. I'll delete my irrelevant comments. And the definition of `f1` seems fine to me, you only always use it as a 4-variate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is in your definition of the limits in the call to `integral3`:

```
integral3( @(y, phi, theta) f3(x, y, phi, theta), p5, p6, @(x,y) p3(x,y), @(x,y) p4(x,y), p1, p2)
```

You're trying to integrate in `y`, `phi` and `theta` from `p5` to `p6`, `p3(x,y)` to `p4(x,y)` and `p1` to `p2`, respectively. `integrate3` allows function-valued limits, but [only in a very specific way](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Functions-of-Multiple-Variables.html#XREFintegral3):

```
q = integral3 (f, xa, xb, ya, yb, za, zb, prop, val, …)

    Numerically evaluate the three-dimensional integral of f using adaptive quadrature
    over the three-dimensional domain defined by xa,
    xb, ya, yb, za, zb (scalars may be finite or infinite). Additionally,
    ya and yb may be scalar functions of x and za, and zb maybe be scalar
    functions of x and y, allowing for integration over non-rectangular
    domains.
```

This actually reflects how integration would work on paper. So what you have is:

```
p5, p6,
@(x,y) p3(x,y), @(x,y) p4(x,y),
p1, p2
```

Your second limits try to depend on *two* variables, whereas they may only depend on one: the first integration variable. But this is fine, since `x` is not an integration variable, it's merely a parameter. So I believe the following should work:

```
integral3(@(y, phi, theta) f3(x, y, phi, theta), p5, p6, @(y) p3(x,y), @(y) p4(x,y), p1, p2)
```

By defining the limits as single-valued functions we basically [curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) your `p3` and `p4` functions to have a single-valued function that depends on the `y` integration variable.

Comment: Thank you.
After following your suggestion.
I need to change `/` into `./` in f1 function definition.
now, it has been running for a couple of minutes while showing warning:
warning: quad2d: Maximum number of sub-tiles reached, accuracy may be low

Comment: @Codelearner777 I would imagine 4d integration to be inherently time-consuming.

Comment: @Codelearner777 regarding your comment edit with a warning: I'm not sure there's much we can do about that. According to the docs only `integrate3` works with non-rectangular domains, `triplequad` doesn't.